# Setting Intervals in Fsharp.Charting

Tags: plot, f#

When using Fsharp.Charting for plotting, is it possible to:

- set grid interval for DateTime value (format hh:mm:ss, for example on X-axis)?
- round X-axis grid value?

---

Comment: FYI OxyPlot has a DateTimeAxis.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what is the configuration that you want to get, but the key point is that F# Charting allows you to set things like grid, ticks and axis properties in various ways - but if your keys are `DateTime` values, the configuration still has to use `float`. The numbers to give it are number of days.

Experimentally, it seems that the following two functions work for converting dates and time spans to floats. I'm completely puzzled as to why you need to use 30/12/1899, but it works.

```
let dtf (d:DateTime) = 
  (d - DateTime(1899,12,30)).TotalDays

let stf (ts:TimeSpan) = 
  ts.TotalDays
```

To specify a grid property you can use:

```
Chart.Line [
  for d in 10 .. 20 ->
    DateTime(2022,1,d), sin(float d / 10.0)]
|> Chart.WithXAxis
    ( Min=dtf(DateTime(2022,1,1)), 
      Max=dtf(DateTime(2022,1,31)), 
      MajorGrid=Grid(Interval=stf(TimeSpan(1,0,0,0)), LineColor=Color.Red))
|> Chart.Show
```

It is also worth noting that FSharp.Charting is pretty much obsolete now and it would be a good idea to use Plotly.NET or something else instead.

Comment: Thank's for quick and excellent answer! However my script says "error FS0039: The value or constructor 'Grid' is not defined." I'm trying to figure out what is missing. (Using Visual Studio 2019, framework: net472 ). And my data contains time value as "hh:mm:ss" (hours:minutes:seconds) which I try to put X-axis and set its interval.